# Model binding POST values with square brackets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, mailchimp

**How can I bind a POSTed parameter named "data[email]" to a model in Asp.Net MVC?**

Posted data:

```
type=subscribe&data%5Bemail%5D=my%40iemail.com
```

Without url encoding:

```
type=subscribe&data[email]=my@email.com
```

The model I want to bind to:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string type {get;set;}
  public string dataemail {get;set;} //What do I do here to 
}
```

The method receiving the POST:

```
public ActionResult Post(MyModel payload)
{
    return Ok(payload);
}
```

#### Background:

MailChimp uses POST for webhooks, and posts some of the values back with square brackets in them. I can't figure out how to model bind that.

I could use Request.Form, but... Would really much rather use model binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the model `data` property to use a dictionay

```
public class MyModel {
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> data { get; set; }
}
```

accessing the email would be done through the dictionary like

```
var email = payload.data["email"];
```

Comment: For future reference, others that might see this... This works great for the example above, but chances are, you are here looking for a way to parse the Mailchimp webhook payload - and the above works for a lot of fields, but not for the "merges" fields, for example: data[merges][FNAME]. I eventually gave up and used Request.Form["data[merges][FNAME]"].ToString() which works just fine, but is less elegant than model binding.

Comment: @Kjensen you could consider creating a custom model binder that would traverse the Form array and construct a strongly typed model. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Yes, I did consider it, but it seemed like overkill, so I left it. But thanks :)